# Скрипт не видит методы класса

Tags: php

Имеется такая проблема: есть класс, и в нем методы. Но когда я пытаюсь вызвать эти методы, php выдает ошибку, что таких методов не существует. Хотя IDE, например, все видит.

Вот класс:

```
<?php
class Config
{
    private static $config = null;
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $userName = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'keep_lab';
    private $lcTimeNames = 'ru_RU';
    private $encoding = 'utf8';
    public static function getConfig()
    {
        if (self::$config === null) {
            self::$config = new self;
        }
        return self::$config;
    }
}
```

Метод вызывается в другом классе.
Классы разнесены по разным файлам и находятся в одной директории.
[исходники классов](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-oop/thread1799933.html#post9494596)

Вот вызов метода:

```
<?php
include_once 'Config.php';

class DataBase{
    // лишнее вырезано
    public static function getDB()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self(Config::getConfig());
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}
// ....
$db = DataBase::getDB();
```

Текст ошибки:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Config::getConfig() in D:\Sergei\Programming\Web-programming\Keep_Notes\www.notes.lb\lib\DataBase.php on line 21
```

Comment: Метод у Вас только один и называется `getConfig()`. Он вызывается без ошибок. Всё остальное закрытые свойства, которые и не должны быть доступны из вне (`private`). Поэтому, пожалуйста, приведите [пример кода, который бы воспроизводил ошибку](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) и выложите сообщение об ошибке PHP, как оно есть. Иначе, без явного описания проблемы, вопрос могут заминусовать или закрыть.

Comment: Если в этот класс дописать любой public метод и вызвать его, он будет работать.

Comment: @MaksimKlimenko, он и так работает, хотя в нём и не реализован доступ к данным из вне. Проблема автора в другом, но и она не воспроизводится.

Comment: Решение данного вопроса на [cyberforum-e](http://www.cyberforum.ru/php-oop/thread1799933.html#post9494616)

Answer (score 1):

Честно говоря, то, что вы, нифига не соображая в программировании, решили сами надергать методов и привести не весь код, а только его обрывки, играет далеко не в вашу пользу. И, возможно, по этому, я не нашел смысла в вашем коде.

Вот так у меня работает:

```
class Config
{
    private static $config = null;
    private static $db = null;
    private $host = 'localhost';
    private $userName = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    private $database = 'keep_lab';
    private $lcTimeNames = 'ru_RU';
    private $encoding = 'utf8';

    private function __construct($config=null)
    {
        if ($config==null) {
            $config = $this->host . '/' . $this->userName . '/' . $this->password . '/' . $this->database . '/' . $this->lcTimeNames . '/' . $this->encoding;
        }

        return $config;
    }

    public static function getConfig()
    {
        if (self::$config === null) {
            self::$config = new self;
        }
        return self::$config;
    }

    public static function getDB()
    {
        if (self::$db === null) {
            self::$db = new self(Config::getConfig());
        }
        return self::$db;
    }
}

$db = Config::getDB();
```

Вашу ошибку воспроизвести не удалось.

Answer (score 0):

**Воспроизводится** на Windows + PHP 5.6.3(из комплекта XAMPP)
***Не*** **воспроизводится** на Linux + PHP 7.0.9

Методом "научного тыка" пришел к следующему примеру

Есть 3 файла:

- A.php - содержит class A,

```php
<?php
class A {
    public static function funcA() {}
}
```

- B.php - содержит class B, подключает A.php и вызывает методы class A

```php
<?php
include_once 'A.php';

class B {
    public static function funcB() {
        A::funcA();
    }
}
```

- run.php подключает B.php и вызывает методы class B

```php
<?php
include_once 'B.php'

B::funcB();
```

Пусть это дело лежит в папке `/path0/1/`
Ошибки не возникнет, если при запуске `php run.php` текущая директория(`CWD`) совпадает с `/path0/1/` и возникает, если `CWD != /path0/1/`
Для воспроизведения ошибки нужно перейти, допустим, на уровень вверх `cd ..` и запустить `php 1/run.php`

"Лечится" подключением файла `A.php` по абсолютному пути

```
require_once __DIR__. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .'Config.php';
```